# Crash: "Check failed: mem_map_.IsValid() couldn't allocate <US_MALE_NAME> stack."

Tags: android-memory

An app has the following crash from Android 11 device TCL BeyondTV4 as reported by Google Play:

```
Thread: Check failed: mem_map_.IsValid() couldn't allocate <US_MALE_NAME> stack.

backtrace:
  #00  pc 0x0000000000038a54  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (abort+172)
  #01  pc 0x0000000000409e4d  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+1696)
  #02  pc 0x000000000000d9d9  /system/lib/libbase.so (android::base::SetAborter(std::__1::function<void (char const*)>&&)::$_3::__invoke(char const*)+48)
  #03  pc 0x000000000000d2e5  /system/lib/libbase.so (android::base::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+224)
  #04  pc 0x000000000012c92f  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::FindOatMethodFor(art::ArtMethod*, art::PointerSize, bool*) (.llvm.15859316012646344063)+422)
  #05  pc 0x000000000012c647  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::GetOatQuickMethodHeader(unsigned int)+190)
  #06  pc 0x000000000042748d  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (void art::StackVisitor::WalkStack<(art::StackVisitor::CountTransitions)0>(bool)+868)
  #07  pc 0x000000000044fc51  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::DumpJavaStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, bool, bool) const+396)
  #08  pc 0x000000000044c06f  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::DumpStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, bool, BacktraceMap*, bool) const+402)
  #09  pc 0x00000000004477a7  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, bool, BacktraceMap*, bool) const+34)
  #10  pc 0x0000000000464c4d  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::DumpCheckpoint::Run(art::Thread*)+688)
  #11  pc 0x000000000046010f  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::ThreadList::RunCheckpoint(art::Closure*, art::Closure*)+354)
  #12  pc 0x000000000045f45d  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::ThreadList::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, bool)+1088)
  #13  pc 0x0000000000409d93  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+1510)
  #14  pc 0x000000000000d9d9  /system/lib/libbase.so (android::base::SetAborter(std::__1::function<void (char const*)>&&)::$_3::__invoke(char const*)+48)
  #15  pc 0x000000000000d2e5  /system/lib/libbase.so (android::base::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+224)
  #16  pc 0x00000000001c2e35  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::gc::accounting::AtomicStack<art::mirror::Object>::Init()+232)
  #17  pc 0x00000000001b4027  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::gc::collector::ConcurrentCopying::PushOntoMarkStack(art::Thread*, art::mirror::Object*)+754)
  #18  pc 0x00000000001b9d81  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::gc::collector::ConcurrentCopying::Copy(art::Thread*, art::mirror::Object*, art::mirror::Object*, art::MemberOffset)+1320)
  #19  pc 0x0000000000128ec1  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::ReadBarrier::Mark(art::mirror::Object*)+680)
  #20  pc 0x00000000000d90f1  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art_quick_read_barrier_mark_introspection+240)
  #21  pc 0x0000000000095b13  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/arm/boot.oat (java.lang.ThreadLocal.getMap+34)
  #22  pc 0x0000000000095929  /apex/com.android.art/javalib/arm/boot.oat (java.lang.ThreadLocal.get+48)
  #23  pc 0x000000000091f03b  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (com.android.server.NetworkManagementSocketTagger.setThreadSocketStatsTag+66)
  #24  pc 0x00000000005461d3  /system/framework/arm/boot-framework.oat (android.net.TrafficStats.getAndSetThreadStatsTag [DEDUPED]+34)
```

The app never access any user account information. What does "US_MALE_NAME" here mean? Could anyone offer a tip on the possible causes?